# Background repeat after float:left

Tags: html, css

I am working on Web Forms page and I have strange issue with .css

I am trying to setup page with:

- Header (Logo.jpg on the left; Page Title in the middle)
- Content (GroupBoxes etc.)

To set header I use following code:

```
 <section class="main-page" style="position: relative; border-top: solid 2px #000">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 45px; padding-left: 10px;">
            <img src="../Images/Origin/logo.jpg" style="height: 45px" />
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
               <div>
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1><%: Title %></h1>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and my .css

```
html {
        background: url("../Images/Origin/background2.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}
hgroup.title {
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

The problem is that background is repeated (as you see in the picture). When I set for example float: left - background is not repeated (which is good) but text is on the left...

[image: sample]

Comment: Please provide a fiddle if possible.

Comment: Yes sure, but how exactly do that?

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and paste your html and css codes over there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ - Add HTML (what is between body), add CSS, add JS. You can add external sources. Hit save. The url you post here. Other people can work on it by forking it.

Comment: Also `<hgroup>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.